# sed token from : delimited string

Tags: regex, shell, sed, token

I tried searching for an answer but lost in questions. Basically I have a shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    exit -1
fi 

processInfo $1
```

At this point, processInfo returns a string of format:
param1:param2:param3:param4:param5

I want to capture param4 into a variable. 
ex:
param4= `processInfo $1 | sed regex`

It seems to be simple with sed and regex but I just lost track of it. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
param4=$(processInfo $1 | awk -F: '{print $4}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
param4=$( processInfo "$1" | cut -d':' -f 4 )
```

Comment: realized later that this is much more light weight than the awk! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
array=($(processInfo $1))
IFS=$saveIFS
echo ${array[3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep your script's positional parameters:

```
IFS=:
set -- $( processInfo "$1" )
param4="$4"
```